# Modify data in Firebase with Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I have just started learning Vuejs. After attempting to follow https://alligator.io/vuejs/vuefire-firebase/ (modifying data section at the bottom of the page), I tried to update information on Firebase and I get the error: 
cannot read property child of undefined. How can I fix this?

```
<script>
import {linesRef} from '../../firebase'
export default {
    firebase: {
        lines: linesRef
    },
    data() {
        return {
            status: 'available'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        hold(key, e) {
            if (confirm("Hold the line?")) {
                function updateStatus(line, sold) {
                    linesRef.lines.child(line['.key'])
                    .child('status').set(sold)
                }
                e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"

            }
            else{
                e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `linesRef.child(line['.key'])` to access the document you want

Comment: but then it says: Cannot read property '.key' of undefined, not sure of what I am missing here

Comment: It's simply `line` not existing or not being passed as a parameter there

Comment: turns out I was looping through the wrong parameter so it was rendered undefined. Thanks for your answer and your tutorial! It helped me so much